# Oracle 11g procedure error with ftp packages

Tags: oracle, plsql, acl, plsqldeveloper

I have met a problem with my database (version is Oracle 11g).

What did I want to do?

- i want to use procedures to upload a file to the ftp server.

How did i do?

- first , i have download the **ftp.pks** and **ftp.pkb** files and I use @**.pks to import this packages.
- and then i code the procedures like this:

  ```
  DECLARE
    l_conn  UTL_TCP.connection;
  BEGIN
    l_conn := ftp.login('192.168.1.102', '21', 'tony', 'tony');
    ftp.ascii(p_conn => l_conn);
    ftp.put(p_conn      => l_conn,
            p_from_dir  => 'MY_DOCS',
            p_from_file => 'aaa.txt',
            p_to_file   => 'test_put.txt');
    ftp.logout(l_conn);
  END;
  ```
- when I run it, the console give me this error information

> ```
>     ORA-24247: network access rejected by ACL
>     ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 17
>     ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 246
>     ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.FTP", line 76
>     ORA-06512: at line 4
> ```

- and for this reason, I created the `ACL` rules with the following code:

  ```
  begin

       DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(
       acl          => 'ftp_conn.xml',
       description  => 'ftp connection',
       principal    => 'SCOTT',
       is_grant     => TRUE,
       privilege    => 'connect');

       DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(
        acl         => 'ftp_conn.xml',
        host        => '192.168.1.102',
        lower_port  => 21,
        upper_port => 21);

  end;
  ```

But, when I run the ftp code again, it also shows that error, so I want know how to fix this.

**`ACL` can allow TCP connection, but when i use ftp package and call '`ftp.put`', The console output is**

> ```
> error at 1 line:
> ORA-29260: network error:not connected
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 212
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 432
> ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.FTP", line 413
> ORA-24247: Network access rejected by acl
> ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.FTP", line 491
> ORA-06512: at line 6
> ```

Comment: Did you commit after asigning the ACL ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade yes,i have commit the changes.

Comment: may this help ? stackoverflow.com/questions/9827038/oracle-11g-migrated-users-have-acl-set-but-cant-hit-utl-http-ora-24247-29273/9858759

Comment: @A.B.Cade hello .i found that i can use tcp connetion,but the when i use ftp package,it will raise error.

Comment: "Network access rejected by acl" sounds that another port is blocked, for some reason. With some FTP client it works fine?

Comment: @SérgioMichels Yeah,I can connected the ftp server with console.and also use ftp.login can connected.but when i use ftp.put,it raise this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the resolve privilege (though it sounds strange...):

```
begin
 DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(
 acl          => 'ftp_conn.xml',
 description  => 'ftp connection',
 principal    => 'SCOTT',
 is_grant     => TRUE,
 privilege    => 'connect');

 DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.add_privilege ( 
acl         => 'ftp_conn.xml', 
principal   => 'SCOTT',
is_grant    => FALSE, 
privilege   => 'resolve', 
position    => NULL, 
start_date  => NULL,
end_date    => NULL);

 DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(
  acl         => 'ftp_conn.xml',
  host        => '192.168.1.102',
  lower_port  => 21,
  upper_port => 21);

end;
/
COMMIT;
```

Comment: i am so sorry ,the error information format is not pretty <br> <code>error at 1 line:
ORA-29260: network error:not connected
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 212
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 432
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.FTP", line 413
ORA-24247: Network access rejected by acl
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.FTP", line 491
ORA-06512: at line 6</code>